# Issue with getting element's data-label and echo the value [jQuery]

Tags: jquery

I do have 2 share button in my page i'd like to get the data-label from each element and show it in specific div.

Here is my code so far,

```
$('.social-toggle').on('click', function () {
    $('.social-networks').not($(this).next()).removeClass('open-menu')
    $(this).next().toggleClass('open-menu');
});

$('.social-networks [class^="social-"]').hover(function () {
    $("#hide").removeClass("hide");
    $('.txt').text($(this).data('label')).show(0);
}, function () {
    $("#hide").addClass("hide");
    $('.txt').text('').hide(0);
});
```

My first element is showing the data, but the next button doesn't show up the value.
Can you guys take a look at see what is wrong with my code.

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="share-button "> <a href="#" class="social-toggle">Share</a>

    <div class="social-networks">
        <ul>

            <div id="hide" class="hide"><div class="txt"></div></div>
            <li class="social-twitter" data-label="Twitter"> <a href="http://www.twitter.com">T</a>

            </li>
            <li class="social-facebook" data-label="Facebook"> <a href="http://www.facebook.com">F</a>

            </li>
            <li class="social-gplus" data-label="Google +"> <a href="http://www.gplus.com">G+</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And also here is [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4dg1nkxa/2/) working demo

Comment: You have two elements with `id="hide"`. That won't work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs have to be unique. `$("#hide")` only selects the first element with this ID. So

```
$("#hide").removeClass("hide");
```

only makes the element in the first DIV visible, it doesn't show the element in the second DIV.

Use relative DOM navigation:

```
$(this).siblings(".hide").removeClass("hide");
```

[Corrected Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/4dg1nkxa/3/)